# Getting error while fetching value using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the below error while fetching value from table.

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'frmDay' in 'on clause'

I am explaining my query below.

```
$sql="select sl.image_id, sl.member_id, sl.subcat_id, sl.date_from, sl.date_to, 
min(sl.from_day) as frmDay, max(sl.to_day) as toDay, sl.image, b.rest_name, 
b.member_id, s.subcat_name, s.subcat_id, d1.day_name as from_day_name, 
d1.day_id, d2.day_name as to_day_name, d2.day_id 
from db_special_images as sl 
left join db_subcategory as s on sl.subcat_id=s.subcat_id 
left join db_restaurant_basic as b on sl.member_id=b.member_id 
left join db_day as d1 on d1.day_id=frmDay 
left join db_day as d2 on d2.day_id=toDay  
group by sl.member_id, sl.subcat_id 
order by sl.image_id desc";
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: You can not use aliasses from select clause in on clause

Comment: Nor can you use aggregate values.

Comment: *I am explaining my query below.* No, you're just pasting it. If you explain it, we might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: I have already given what the error i am getting.i am getting the error in this line `left join db_day as d1 on d1.day_id=frmDay `.

Comment: ...and the first comment tells you why you're getting that error.

Comment: I have taken the max and min value and joining the tables as per that column but getting the error.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Can you please check this error.